# I can not understand how advanced-For-Loop works

Tags: java, for-loop, ternary-operator

I learned that Advanced_For_Loop can take exactly two expressions.
I don't know how it does work when it has three. I mean: for(expression1 : expression2 : expression3).
And I don't know how it iterates in this code...

```
   private Sheet fieldVsTime(Workbook wb, String _title,List<PivotField>
   _pivots, List<PivotField> _all,boolean _periods,Map<String, String> 
   _yAxesMapping) {

    for (PivotField pivot : _all == null ? _pivots : _all) {
        List<PivotField> list = pivot.getPivot();
        if (list != null) {
            for (PivotField pivotField : list) {
                int publishDate = Integer.parseInt(pivotField.getValue().toString());
                if (_periods) {
                    publishDate = (publishDate / 10) * 10;
                }
                if (publishDate < minYear) {
                    minYear = publishDate;
                }
                if (publishDate > maxYear) {
                    maxYear = publishDate;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the `? :` ternary operator.

Comment: *Enhanced* `for` loop, not *advanced* `for` loop.

Comment: I wish the range-based for loop, a.k.a. foreach loop, wasn't colloquially called "enhanced" for loop. It's only enhanced with respect to pre-1.5 Java. It's enhanced in the sense that it now has two syntaxes instead of one. I prefer not to think of one syntax as being more enhanced than the other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It only has two expressions:

```
for (PivotField pivot : (_all == null ? _pivots : _all))
     ----------------   -------------------------------
            1                       2
```

The second expression `(_all == null ? _pivots : _all)` returns either `_pivots` or `_all`, depending on whether or not `_all == null`.

Answer (score 4):

Equivalent to this code:

```
List<PivotField> pivotFields;
if( _all == null ) {
    pivotFields = _pivots;
}
else {
    pivotFields = _all;
}

for (PivotField pivot : pivotFields) {
    ...
}
```